# NSTextView copy paste NSTextAttachment on mac os

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I have use the NSTextView,and inset a image NSTextAttachment. when i select and copy it ,and then paste it,it will show pasted image in textview, but i cannot got content string from NSTextView.attributedString. why ?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution yet?

Comment: fix this by use custom type:              let newContent = content.replace(String(c), new: "", mode: .literal)
            NSPasteboard.general().addTypes([CustomParsteFormat.Emotion], owner: nil)
            NSPasteboard.general().setString(newContent, forType: CustomParsteFormat.Emotion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Not sure if it is exactly what you want, but I wanted to be able to copy and paste an NSTextAttachment's string representation.

I ended up overriding `func writeSelection(to pboard: NSPasteboard, type: String) -> Bool` in my custom NSTextView class:

```
override func writeSelection(to pboard: NSPasteboard, type: String) -> Bool {
    let selectedAttributedString = attributedString().attributedSubstring(from: selectedRange())
    let selectedAttributedStringCopy = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: selectedAttributedString)

    selectedAttributedStringCopy.enumerateAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName, in: NSMakeRange(0,(selectedAttributedString.string.characters.count)), options: .reverse, using:  {(_ value: Any?, _ range: NSRange, _ stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in

        if let textAttachment = value as? NSTextAttachment, let textAttachmentCell = textAttachment.attachmentCell as? YouCustomTextAttachmentCellClass {
            var range2: NSRange = NSRange(location: 0,length: 0)
            let attributes = selectedAttributedStringCopy.attributes(at: range.location, effectiveRange: &range2)

            selectedAttributedStringCopy.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: NSMutableAttributedString(string: textAttachmentCell.yourStringRepresentation))
            selectedAttributedStringCopy.addAttributes(attributes, range: range)

            //  selectedAttributedStringCopy.insert(attachmentAttributedString, at: range.location)

        }
    })

    pboard.clearContents()
    pboard.writeObjects([selectedAttributedStringCopy])

    return true
}
```

Note that I am using a custom NSTextAttachmentCell class that also remembers it's string representation.